# CMS for a website to read ebooks online, and order physical copies

Tags: cms, books

It should have ability to read books online and for some books to order physical copy.

I was thinking WordPress.

Edit:
To clarify. It's website for non-profit and books will be open for anyone to read. There should also be an option to download book or order hardcopy. 
So far I think I'll go with WordPress and flipbook plugin. But all suggestions are welcome.

Comment: WordPress, or Drupa (which has [a S.E site](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/)), or maybe you should start your journey at http://www.cmsmatrix.org/ ?

Comment: Thanks @Mawg, didn't know about cms matrix and it looks interesting for comparing. As for drupal, I heard it was good for some things but never really got to learn about it. But will check if its good for this.

Comment: If no one else posts an answer, please come back and post your own and accept it, as that would help others in future

Comment: Sure thing. When I decide on what I will use I'll post it here.

Comment: When you write ".org", should we understand anything beyond the particular domain name choice? In particular, is it for a non-profit, or did you want to convey any such information?

Comment: Should everyone be able to read all books online for free without registering?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide more details, how the CMS should work. For example: Do you want to upload ebooks (EPUB? PDF? …) which the CMS should convert to HTML? Or do you enter the HTML directly? Should each book be on one webpage, or divided into multiple pages? Can an ebook only be read after buying access to it?

Comment: @Nicolas Yes and yes. It's for non-profit and everyone should be able to read it for free.

Comment: @Unor It should be a collection  of public domain books which  are mostly in .pdf So my solution  so far is  WordPress with flipbook plugin for display g pdfs.

Comment: There should also be option to download or order hardcopy of a book. For order it seems better to have just a form then install whole woocomerce...

Comment: Cool, please edit your question to include that information (and also info regarding unor's questions) thanks :-)